# hide web-app source on a second server

Tags: php, mysql, security, include

I made a web based program for a customer, and I want to install the app on a local server of him.

I don't want to give him all the source until he has paid for it, so my idea was to store most of the core code on an external server, and only have a kind of `include` on his server, so he would not be able to see / copy / change the actual PHP code.

I know I can use `include()` with a URL as soon as I have changed the corresponding entry in the `PHP.ini` file, but is there a more secure way of doing this?

Also, what configuration should my server have so that the PHP code on his local server would be able to read the PHP on mine? Wouldn't that pose a huge security risk if I allow other servers to "load" my PHP code?

(Notice that I use a free Web hosting service as the "second server" and I don't have any access to the conf files.)

I hope I've explained my situation well enough.

Comment: Keep it on your server until they pay for it.

Comment: it's not that simple, he wants to be able to "track" the development state, and also he wants to test the application.

Comment: contracts\licenseing is the only real 'protection'. It's not a great look if you have paying customers an are using a free web host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including your php remotely is a) yes a huge security risk and b) not accomplishing much, since your customer can also "see" that remote code, copy/paste it, and have it all in his possession.

**Option 1: Don't give away the app!**

If your customer wants to test the app, deploy it to a server that *you* control. Let him see/use/test the app, without access to the source code.

**Option 2: Encode it**

If you absolutely have to give your app to the customer and yet need to protect it, look at encoding solutions. We use http://www.ioncube.com/ to encode/protect PHP code that we deploy to a customer's server.

Comment: well i dont have any budget for any software.

how exactly could he see my code if there is only this line of code on his server ? include( http://second.server.com/core.php );

Comment: Because "second.server.com/core.php" would have to be public, serving up your PHP code as plaintext in order for the remote include to work. Your customer just has to load that URL and copy/paste your remote code.

Comment: oh ok i understand. did not know that it must be plain text :/

Comment: I think option 1 is your best bet. If he just wants to test the app and track progress, you can host it on a public server that only you control. No reason he needs the source code.

Comment: sure, but it's a bit tricky, he's a kind of person that if i would say " first pay for it", he would say " i dont really need that app, get the hell out of here"....

Comment: but youre absolutely right ! i might have to think about it, i just wanted to clear out the idea of having the code externally

Comment: @Ace: If your customers are unlikely to actually pay you for your product, you need to reevaluate your customers.